# Nothing in my "Download" Folder

Tags: downloads

I'm new to Ubuntu. I've downloaded a few apps:  Pidgin, Wine, YM.  Nothing I have downloaded shows up in the "download" folder. I have to do a search for it. Why don't they show up in my "download" folder?  What is the "download" folder for exactly?? Shouldn't DL's go there by default, as in other Operating Systems? Thanks for the help.

Comment: How did you download them?

Answer (score 3):

The Download folder by default stores all of your downloads from your web browser. If you download an app through there then it should show up, unless you defined another folder (In Firefox it's in `Preferences > General`).

If you installed the apps with either `apt-get` or the `Ubuntu Software Center` then the apps will be installed to their proper places directly.